# Adding pandas series on end of each pandas dataframe's row

Tags: python, pandas

I've had issues finding a concise way to append a series to each row of a dataframe, with the series labels becoming new columns in the df. All the values will be the same on each of the dataframes' rows, which is desired.

I can get the effect by doing the following:

```
df["new_col_A"] = ser["new_col_A"]
.....
df["new_col_Z"] = ser["new_col_Z"]
```

But this is so tedious there must be a better way, right?

Comment: Hello friend, mind explaining what exactly you want to do, you just want a quick code that can append multiple series at once?

Comment: `pd.concat([df, ser], axis=1)`?

Comment: Hey, sorry if it was vague. What I'm hoping for is something which takes a dataframe like this:

`df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2], [1, 3], [4, 6]], columns=['A', 'B'])`

which when "concated" with a series like this:
`ser = pd.Series(["a","b"],index=["C",D"])`

will give a result like this:

`df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2,"a","b"], [1, 3,"a","b"], [4, 6,"a","b"]], columns=['A', 'B','C','D'])`

Comment: I found the suggestion from @BeRT2me, simply adds it to the bottom and introduces NaNs all over the table.

Comment: Add all of that as an *Edit* to your question, not as a comment~

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given:

```
# df

   A  B
0  1  2
1  1  3
2  4  6

# ser

C    a
D    b
dtype: object
```

Doing:

```
df[ser.index] = ser
print(df)
```

Output:

```
   A  B  C  D
0  1  2  a  b
1  1  3  a  b
2  4  6  a  b
```

Comment: Thanks heaps, and also thanks for the tip about further comments